# Resize images with Javascript to fit them within the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm calling an API that returns a URL to an image, the image could be any size and it's completely random.

I'm trying to resize images to fit within the page, ensuring the content is not pushed below the fold, or that the image doesn't hit the width of the page.

I've written some Javascript below, I've been testing it and am getting some strange results - the console logs are saying that the image is one size, but the element selector in Chrome's dev tools is usually saying something completely different. I'm sure I've made some basic mistake in my code, if you could take a look that would be great.

Javascript sets viewport height and width, checks if a photo src is available. Once the image has loaded, it checks if the natural dimensions are greater than that of the viewport, if so it attempts to resize - this is where the script is failing.

```
            //check viewport
            var viewportWidth = getWidth();
            var viewportHeight = getHeight();

            //get the media
            if (data[2] == "photo") {
                var tweetImage = document.getElementById("tweetImage");
                //when it loads check the size against the browser size
                tweetImage.onload = function () {
                    console.log('image height: ' + tweetImage.naturalHeight);
                    console.log('viewport height: ' + viewportHeight);

                    //does it matter if its landscape?
                    if (viewportWidth - tweetImage.naturalWidth < 1) {
                        tweetImage.width = Math.floor(tweetImage.naturalWidth - (viewportWidth - tweetImage.naturalWidth) * 1.2);
                        console.log('w');
                    } else if (Math.floor(viewportHeight - tweetImage.naturalHeight) < 1) {
                        console.log('h');
                        console.log(viewportHeight - tweetImage.naturalHeight);
                        console.log('changed result: ' + Math.floor(tweetImage.naturalHeight - (Math.abs(viewportHeight - tweetImage.naturalHeight))));
                        tweetImage.height = Math.floor(tweetImage.naturalHeight - (Math.abs(viewportHeight - tweetImage.naturalHeight)*1.2));

                    } else {
                        tweetImage.height = Math.floor(viewportHeight / 2);

                    }
                    tweetImage.align = "center";
                    tweetImage.paddingBottom = "10px";

                };
                //tweetImage.height = Math.floor(viewportHeight / 2);
                tweetImage.src = data[3];

            }
```

Comment: Have you looked at a CSS-based solution liked viewport height units? http://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: @DesignerGuy using this along with bootstrap img-reponsive did the trick. Post as an answer and I will accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a CSS-based solution like viewport height units.

```
.example {
    height: 50vh; // 50% of viewport height
}
```

See http://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/